# Drupal CKEditor image2 plugin only works after reloading wyiwyg

Tags: drupal, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor with media 2 and image2. When I insert an image with media the markup is

```
<p><mediawrapper data=""><img alt="" class="file-default media-element" data-fid="3" data-media-element="1" height="960" src="/sites/default/files/banner_images/image.JPG" typeof="foaf:Image" width="1280" /></mediawrapper></p>
```

If I select the image and try to use image2 it doesn't pick up the image URL.

If I then click Source and then Source again so I'm back to the wysiwyg mode I can select the image and image2 picks it up fine.

The markup then looks like this

```
<p><img alt="" src="/sites/default/files/banner_images/image.JPG" /></p>
```

I've tried calling updateElement() after inserting the media image but with no success. I used:

```
for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances ){
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
}
```

Does anyone know of a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your markup on StackOverflow is broken so there is unable to see your samples.

But the problem you describe is very very similar to default CKEditor tags striping behavior. CKEditor ACL filters will remove all unknown (or restricted) tags from content area. To fix this issue you need to add this line to your `config.js` (in case of Drupal use according text field in admin panel):

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I've fixed the code in my question.

in my ckeditor.config.js file in my theme I have

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
    config.allowedContent = true;
};

But it hasn't fixed the issue.

It seems to be that the image2 plugin isn't aware of the image attributes until the source is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on drupal.org, here:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2400455#comment-11135553

Comment: While this might solve the problem, link only answers are not considered good. Please consider adding some related codes/analysis data to support your answer...